# $(window).load vs. window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between:

```
$(window).load(function() {
loadSlideShow();
});
```

and

```
window.addEventListener('load',loadSlideShow());
```

The function loadSlideShow() creates a slideshow; it waits for all of the images to load, and then adds the controls to the slideshow, in the middle of the image (it bases the position of the controls on the height of the image).

When using window.addEventListener, the controls would sometimes be added before the image had actually loaded.  So the image height would be 0 and the controls would be placed at the very top of the slideshow, and not in the middle.

Once I changed to $(window).load, the error went away.

I'm not sure why there would be a difference between the two.

Comment: There's definitely a difference between `window.addEventListener('load',loadSlideShow());` and `window.addEventListener('load',loadSlideShow);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is implemented wrong which will make a difference:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadSlideShow());
```

It should be:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadSlideShow);
```

The way you were doing it would call `loadSlideShow()` immediately without waiting for the event. The corrected way will operate the same as your jQuery version.